# VBA script to copy specific rows in Excel from a given workbook to a new workbook if specific value is found in a given column

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for the past 48 hours and I couldn't find anything. Keep in mind I have very basic programming knowledge and I might have overlooked something to fit my needs without understanding the code behind it.

I have an excel workbook with a sheet containing all of the data.
It's a list of shipments going in and out of a port.
Now when something is loaded, a "Date Loaded" cell is populated with the date automatically.
What I need for every row that has a blank "Date Loaded" cell to be copied to a new workbook which will be named by the date it was generated (i.e.:031814-PM) depending on the time of the day, PM could be AM.

Now I might not need all the columns to be copied to the new workbook. I need a way to exclude those columns during the copying process.

I want the VBA script to be called with a button that will be at the top of the data worksheet so that when we click on it, the new workbook is generated.

Comment: There are many examples of "copy cells to another workbook" on this site...why did none of them work for you?

Comment: For some reason I have come across many applications of copying full worksheets or ranges of rows/columns but not one that worked the way I wanted it to. I'll just get down to it and figure it out I guess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: this site is good for help on problems, but you won't find many who will do the whole thing for you.  My suggestion would be to either: post what you have tried and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: I'll do some further testing before posting anything else. Thanks for the reply!